# how to remove noise from a special area in Matlab

Tags: matlab, filtering, noise

I have a an image of size 180x220 containing some noise in the region for example (145:180,1:65).

My question is how to remove the noise in this region without affecting the other parts of the image using Matlab.

Thank you very much.

Edit: I want to remove the noise in the regions (1:146,1:25) and (1:15,25,174) from the following image:

[image]

Comment: very hard to answer without knowing what type of noise and without seeing an image.

Comment: thank you, I added an image and specified the exact region from which I want to remove the noise.

Comment: @GambaOsaca: hmmm that doesn't really look like noise, more like the output of some sharpening filter or some such...are you at liberty to say what this is an image of?

Comment: It's a depth map. acquired by a depth sensor.

Comment: the noise correspond to a region that's outside the maximum range of the sensor (5 meters).

Comment: @GambaOsaca: why do you want to de-noise that? Why not crop the image then? Purely cosmetic reasons or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this would go something like

```
% filter image in-place
img(145:180, 1:65) = medfilt2(img(145:180, 1:65));
```

Note that most filters require some context of the region of interest to do a proper interpolation/averaging/etc., so you might want to take this approach:

```
% Note: increase ROI by 10 on each side
offset = 10;
img_tmp = img(145-offset : 180+offset, 1 : 65+offset); 

% apply filter
img_tmp = medfilt2(img_tmp, [additional parameters]);

% put filtered image back in its proper place
img(145:180, 1:65) = img_tmp(offset:end-offset+1, 1:end-offset+1);
```

Comment: thank you Rody, my image is a depth map, it contains only one layer.
I attached an example image.

Answer (score 2):

```
img = double(imread('img.jpg'));
h = fspecial('gaussian', hsize, sigma); % decide how to filter the image
img_filt = imfilter(img, h, 'replicate');
```

now, use the filtered image only in the noise region

```
img(145:180,1:65,:) = img_filt(145:180,1:65,:);
```

**Edit:** After you posted the image I guess you want simply replace the noised region by the vanilla color?
If so, then do the following (assuming gray image):

```
med_pixel = median(img(:)); % detect the dominant color
img(1:146,1:25) = med_pixel;
img(1:15,25,174) = med_pixel;
```

... and so on

Comment: +1, although `img(145:180,1:65,:) = imfilter(img(145:180,1:65,:), h, 'replicate');` would be far less demanding on resources.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis, I agree. But this can allow to use very large (LF) filter to clean the noise using the actual image. I guess it depends on the speed/quality requirements.

Comment: true, it depends on the type and size of filter, and therefore the surroundings of the ROI.